# Find an orthogonal matrix P that diagonalises the matrix B

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B be a symmetric matrix that has eigenvectors (2, 1, 1) and (0, 1, −1).
Find an orthogonal matrix P that diagonalises the matrix B. What is P^-1

Comment: Only two eigenvectors in a 3D-space, you will not be able to diagonalise this matrix, sorry.

Comment: I know, but isn't there a way to find the third eigenvertor? since the text says that B is symmetric?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use the spectral theorem for that.